# How do I calculate the SHA-256 checksum of a Request in Nextjs 13 App Router?

Tags: next.js, webhooks, signature, app-router

I have a webhook in a nextjs 13 app that uses the new app router. The incoming lemon squeezy request is signed and provides that signature in the `x-signature` header.

According to their documentation [here](https://docs.lemonsqueezy.com/help/webhooks#node-js-example) the signature must be calculated from the raw body. How can I access this in an app router route?

i tried this but it (obviously) won't work as this does not process the raw but the parsed body. (The body object in the incoming `Request` object is of type ReadableStream by the way)

```js
const isSignatureValid = (requestSignature: string | null, body: any) => {
  const secret = process.env.LMS_SECRET || "";
  const hmac = crypto.createHmac("sha256", secret);

  const calculatedHash = hmac.update(JSON.stringify(body)).digest("hex");
  console.log("found signature:", `[${requestSignature}]`);
  console.log("calculated hash:", `[${calculatedHash}]`);

  const digest = Buffer.from(calculatedHash, "utf8");
  const signature = Buffer.from(requestSignature || "", "utf8");

  return digest.length === signature.length && crypto.timingSafeEqual(digest, signature);
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it. I first loaded the body of the `Response` object, which is of type `ReadableStream<Uint8Array>` into a Buffer. I used this method

```js
async function toBuffer(stream: ReadableStream<Uint8Array>) {
  const list = [];
  const reader = stream.getReader();
  while (true) {
    const { value, done } = await reader.read();
    if (value) list.push(value);
    if (done) break;
  }
  return Buffer.concat(list);
}
```

which I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74421537/1934396).

After doing this the stream is consumed and you can no longer use the `req.json()` method. However, you can simply `toString()` the body and then parse the json like so:

```js
  const b = await toBuffer(req.body!);

  const bString = b.toString();
  console.log("b.toString() ");
  console.log(bString);

  const bJson = JSON.parse(bString);
  console.log("JSON.parse(b.toString()) ");
  console.log(bJson);
```